# jQuery Event Binding is applied to whole body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a some event functions to dynamically generated elements on a page.

I've used the Event delegation as follows.

```
//For Static Element
$(".get_flickr_image").click(function(){
      getFlickrImages();
});

// For Dynamic Element
$(document).on("click", $(".get_more_flickr_image"), function(){
     getFlickrImages();
});
```

But for some reason, the second function is called whenever I click anywhere on the document. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
// For Dynamic Element
$(document).on("click",".get_more_flickr_image", function(){
     getFlickrImages();
});
```

You're not passing the `selector` correctly.

Answer (score 3):

[**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) does not have an overload for passing jQuery objects. Pass the selector as a string instead

```
$(document).on("click", ".get_more_flickr_image", function(){
     getFlickrImages();
});
```